# symfony hateoas and jms serialization

Tags: symfony, serialization, hateoas, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity Customer that i want to have both Hatoas Links and custom serialization

```
/**
 * Customer ORM Entity
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @Hateoas\Relation("self", href = @Hateoas\Route("get_customers", parameters = { "customer" = "expr(object.getId())" }))
 * @Hateoas\Relation("customers", href = @Hateoas\Route("cget_customers"))))
 */
```

That is the annotation for the hateoas links

```
AppBundle\Entity\Customer:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    virtual_properties:
        getFullName:
            serialized_name: full_name
            type: string
```

That is my yaml configuration for the jms serialization but for some reason it also remove the hateoas links.

How can i get it back? Tell to the serializer to not remove the _links property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Hateoas documentation](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas#configuring-links) it says:

> Important: you must configure both the Serializer and Hateoas the same way. E.g. if you use YAML for configuring Serializer, use YAML for configuring Hateoas.

For example, use the [YAML format](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas#yaml) for configuration and your issue should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

As @takeit say, you should use the same configuration used with the serializer. For your example try this:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Customer:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    virtual_properties:
        getFullName:
            serialized_name: full_name
            type: string
    relations:
        -
        href:
          route: get_customers
          parameters:
              customer: expr(object.getId())
  #       absolute: 0
        customers:
          route: cget_customers
```

Hope this help